# confused about implementing class into xml serialization

Tags: c#, wpf, xmlserializer

I was reading a book on serialization. I am confused about implementing class portion or simply put i don't really understand classes(maybe).

Basically i have my application designed in this way following the steps of my book. I just dont understand the class of FileSaving and maybe where to implement it. I would like to start using serialization to save elements of a form and reloading it via xml using a "Save" and "Load" button. I have a textbox and users keys in strings into the Majorversiontextbox and this textbox.text is then stored as MajorversionLabel. Please clarify my doubts and help me out with serialization. Thanks! I will clarify any doubts about my question.

EDIT

Question 1, Why do i need to have this FileSaving class when I am only getting values from the content from the label and saving it into a xml file. Question 2, is my FileSaving class declared correctly? Question 3, why do i need Get and Set over here?

```
    public partial class Window1 : Window
{
...
...

        public class FileSaving
        {
            private string major;

            public string Majorversion
            {   
                get
                {   
                return major;
                }
                set
                {
                    major = value;
                }
            }
        }
        private void MajorversionupdateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        MajorversionresultLabel.Content = MajorversionTextBox.Text;
        MajorversionupdateButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        MajorversionTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        MajorversionmodifyButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }
        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string savepath;
            SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
            // Default file extension
            DialogSave.DefaultExt = "txt";
            // Available file extensions
            DialogSave.Filter = "XML file (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            // Adds a extension if the user does not
            DialogSave.AddExtension = true;
            // Restores the selected directory, next time
            DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
            // Dialog title
            DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";
            // Startup directory
            DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
            DialogSave.ShowDialog();
            savepath = DialogSave.FileName;
            DialogSave.Dispose();
            DialogSave = null;

            Filesaving abc = new FileSaving();
            abc.Majorversion = MajorversionLabel.Content;
            FileStream savestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FileSaving));
            serializer.Serialize(savestream, abc);
        }

        private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string loadpath;
            Stream checkStream = null;
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog DialogLoad = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            DialogLoad.Multiselect = false;
            DialogLoad.Filter = "XML file (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if ((bool)DialogLoad.ShowDialog())
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((checkStream = DialogLoad.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        loadpath = DialogLoad.FileName;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Problem occured, try again later");
            }

            FileSaving abc = new FileSaving();
            FileStream loadstream = new FileStream(loadpath, FileMode.Open);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FileSaving));
            abc=(FileSaving)serializer.Deserialize(loadstream);
            loadstream.Close();
            MajorversionresultLabel.Content = abc.Majorversion;
        }
```

}

Comment: @Marc Gravell please see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. because `XmlSerializer` is an object serializer, and works from the type definition
2. sure, that'll work
3. strictly speaking you don't, but the current version looks fine; `XmlSerializer` works for public properties or fields; you could simplify to an automatically-implemented property though: `public string MajorVersion {get;set;}`

But if you only want to save a single string value - is xml overfkill? `File.WriteAllText` / `File.ReadAllText` may be simpler.

Comment: Hi marc, thanks for your prompt reply. My application contains more than just a string value, it consists of combo boxes items, checkboxes and strings. Xml still a better choice here?